# Тире или запятая: как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как приедешь — позвони мне.
Как приедешь, позвони мне.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос вкуса, не более.

Сама проблема называется тире между придаточным и главным. Понятно же, что запятая "законная", а тире факультативно. Но объяснимо: просящий позвонить более категоричен.

> [§ 172.](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire) Тире ставится между двумя предложениями, если они связаны
> по смыслу как придаточное (на первом месте) с главным (на втором
> месте), но подчинительные союзы отсутствуют, например:
>
> *Назвался груздем – полезай в кузов.*
>
> *Лес рубят – щепки летят.*
>
> *Сам запутался – сам и распутывайся; умел кашу заварить – умей ее и расхлебывать; любишь кататься – люби и саночки возить.*

Другой [источник знаний](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37430.php?ELEMENT_ID=37430&PAGEN_1=5) глаголет:

> **ТИРЕ В СЛОЖНОСОЧИНЕННОМ И СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ**
>
> **В сложносочиненном предложении тире ставится:**
>
> 1. Если во второй части сложносочиненного предложения содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление, то тире
>    ставится между частями вместо запятой: Оковы тяжкие падут, темницы
>    рухнут – и свобода вас примет радостно у входа (А.С.Пушкин).
> 2. Тире предпочтительнее запятой, если обе части сложносочиненного предложения или хотя бы одна из частей является назывным предложением,
>    то есть предложением с главным членом – существительном в именительном
>    падеже и с отсутствием глагола-сказуемого: "Еще год, два – и
>    старость", - думала королева и всячески пыталась бороться с
>    надвигающейся бедой. Секунда – и Белоснежка замертво падает на пол.
> 3. Сложносочиненное предложение большого размера может распадаться на две части, одна из которых, а часто и обе, оказываются распространены
>    и осложнены внутри себя. В этом случае между частями можно поставить
>    тире: Ночью, когда теряются краски и предметы становятся серыми и
>    размытыми, королева приходит в свою потайную комнату – и начинается
>    колдовство.
>
> **В сложноподчиненном предложении тире ставится:**
>
> 1. Тире употребляется, когда главной части предшествует придаточная изъяснительная: О чем принц рассказывал мгновенно влюбившейся в него
>    Белоснежке – она так и не могла никогда вспомнить.  В этом случае
>    нарушение порядка следования частей подчеркивает экспрессивный смысл
>    всей фразы. Особенно часто тире употребляется, если используются союзы
>    ЛИ…ИЛИ, ЛИ…ЛИ: Понимает ли королева, что она не может соперничать с
>    юной принцессой, или ей кажется, что она помолодеет от своих
>    колдовских притираний, - это вопрос сложный. Дополнительные условия
>    постановки тире появляются, если в главной части есть слова ЭТО, ВОТ:
>    Что принц нашел в Белоснежке – это его личное дело.
> 2. Тире возможно, если придаточное условное или уступительное предшествует главной части: "Если кто-нибудь придет и захочет выманить
>    тебя из домика – не открывай дверь!" - напутствовали гномики
>    Белоснежку..
> 3. Придаточная часть может быть неполным предложением с пропуском сказуемого, при этом части всего предложения строятся параллельно, а
>    тире стоит вместо пропущенного сказуемого главной части, к которому и
>    относится придаточное: Одни считают, что для поддержания красоты
>    следует вести здоровый образ жизни, другие – что надо покупать дорогие
>    кремы для лица.
> 4. Если придаточные части предшествуют главной, причем придаточных несколько, тогда главную часть можно рассмотреть как обобщающую для
>    группы придаточных, поэтому лучше перед ней поставить тире (по
>    аналогии с правилом пунктуации при однородных членах предложения):
>    Почему Белоснежка поверила старушке, почему не насторожилась, зачем
>    взяла отравленное яблоко – этого гномики не могли себе объяснить.
> 5. Еще одним важным фактором, допускающим постановку тире между главной и придаточной частями, оказывается интонационное членение
>    сложноподчиненного предложение: "А ты уверена – нужно ли действительно
>    мыть руки перед едой или можно только отряхнуть?" - робко спросили
>    гномики.
>
> **ВНИМАНИЕ!**
>
> ***Перед тире во всех рассмотренных выше случаях по условиям контекста может оказаться запятая.*** Это возможно, если перед местом постановки
> тире находится обособленный член предложения или придаточное
> предложение. В этом случая пишущий ставит два не связанных между собой
> знака: запятую, закрывающую один оборот, и тире, стоящее между частями
> сложного предложения.